# How to centralize a cell vertically when in the presence of \vbox with equation in the same row?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, vertical

I'm trying to centralize vertically the first column of this table, but when I insert the equations at the second column, the first doesn't recpect the vertical centering. What can I do?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}  

\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{array} 

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{4cm}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{5cm}}
        \toprule
        Models & Matrix \\ 
        \midrule
        Model 1 & \vbox{    \begin{equation}
                     \begin{bmatrix}
                      1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1
                    \end{bmatrix}
                    \end{equation}} \\
        Model 2 & \vbox{    \begin{equation}
                    \begin{bmatrix}
                    1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1
                    \end{bmatrix}
                    \end{equation}} \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you should not use `\vbox` in a latex document at all, table cells can use vbox, vtop or vcenter by specifying `b`, `p` or `m` in the column specification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply a `$\vcenter{...}$` to the `\vbox`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}  

\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{array} 

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{4cm}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{5cm}}
        \toprule
        Models & Matrix \\ 
        \midrule
        Model 1 & $\vcenter{\vbox{    \begin{equation}
                     \begin{bmatrix}
                      1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1
                    \end{bmatrix}
                    \end{equation}}}$ \\
        Model 2 & $\vcenter{\vbox{    \begin{equation}
                    \begin{bmatrix}
                    1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1
                    \end{bmatrix}
                    \end{equation}}}$ \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

A variant of the `m`  solution, with an improved vertical spacing:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{@{}>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{4cm}>{\centering\arraybackslash\vspace{-\baselineskip}\equation}m{5cm} <{\endequation\vspace{-\belowdisplayskip}}@{}}
        \toprule
        Models & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Matrix} \\
        \midrule
        Model 1 & \begin{bmatrix}
                      1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1
                    \end{bmatrix} \\
        Model 2 &
                    \begin{bmatrix}
                    1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1
                    \end{bmatrix}
                    \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I wonder, why math environment `gather` and `align` don't work in tables but other enclose by for example `\[ ... \]` works?

Comment: @Zarko they do work but you have to nest in `{}` to hide any `&` (which is a deficiency that's probably fixable)

Comment: +1 for not having a `\vbox` on show.

Answer (score 3):

Use `\begin{minipage}{\linewidth} ... \end{minipage}` instead of `\vbox{...}`.

If you have many of these matrices, define a command:

```
\newcommand\eqmatrix[2]%
   {\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \begin{equation}
    \begin{bmatrix}
    #1
    \end{bmatrix}
    \label{#2}
    \end{equation}
    \end{minipage}%
   }
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}  

\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{array} 
\newcommand\eqmatrix[2]%
   {\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \begin{equation}
    \begin{bmatrix}
    #1
    \end{bmatrix}
    \label{#2}
    \end{equation}
    \end{minipage}%
   }

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{4cm}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{5cm}}
  \toprule
  Models & Matrix \\ 
  \midrule
  Model 1 & \eqmatrix{1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1}{m1}\\
  Model 2 & \eqmatrix{1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1}{m2}\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```